# Getting No such property: params for class: Terraform_workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am getting an error when i run the jenkins pipeline.
Getting No such property: params for class: Terraform_workspace.
Below is the pipelineJob in which i have defined the parameter.

```
pipelineJob('Terraform_Create_Workspace') {
  description("Deploy Workspace in Terraform")
  logRotator(-1, 300)
  parameters {
    choiceParam('EnvToDeploy', ['dev', 'prod'], 'Create new workspace in Terraform')
    choiceParam('appBranchType', ['main', 'feature'] 'Select the branch')
    stringParam('appBranchName', '')
    booleanParam('invokedbyBB', true, '')
  }

  definition {
    cps {
      script(readFileFromWorkspace(Terraform_workspace.groovy))
      sandbox()
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the content of groovy script.

```
EnvToDeploy = []
def envDir = "${EnvToDeploy}"
def appbranch
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

if (**params.invokedbyBB**) {
    appbranch = "develop"
    appBranchName = "develop"
} else {
    switch(EnvToDeploy) {
        case "dev":
             switch(appBranchType) {
                case "main":
                     appbranch = "main"
                     break
                default:
                    appbranch = "feature/${appBranchName}"
                    break
             }
        case "prod":
             switch(appBranchType) {
                case "main":
                     appbranch = "main"
                     break
                default:
                    appbranch = "feature/${appBranchName}"
                    break
             }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error in the params.invokedbyBB line.
Can anyone please help me out here?

Tried changing the method of calling the params but nothing worked.